# Getting different data in ajax response froms second time

Tags: ajax, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I am encountering  a problem which I am not able to find out why.

I am using spring mvc and I am sending ajax request to one of my controller.

```
      $.get("<c:url value="/createcomment" />", {id: pageid , newcomment : newcomment})
       .done(function(data){
         $("#newcomment"+data.pageId).val('');
        var html = '<tr><td>'+
                   '<div class="pull-left">'+
                   '<img class="img-rounded" src="resources/profile-pics/male/small.jpg" alt="">'+
                   '</div><div class="span4"><ul class="nav nav-stacked">'+
                   '<li><font size="2"><i class="icon-user"></i>'+data.account.firstName+'&nbsp;'+data.account.lastName+'</font></li>'+
                   '<li><font size="2">'+data.text+'</font></li><li><font size="1">'+data.postingDate+
                   '</font></li></ul></div></td></tr>';
        $(html).inserAfter($("#tr"+data.pageId));
      }
```

When i refresh the page and send the request i get the following desired object.

[image]

and when I send it second time again i get Some Document Object.

[image]

I don't understand what is happening wrong.

[image]

```
             @RequestMapping(value="/createcomment",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Comment createComment(@RequestParam(value="id")final String pageId,@RequestParam(value="newcomment")final String text, 
        final HttpServletRequest request ,final WebRequest req){

    final Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.setId(GenerateUID.generate());
    comment.setText(text);
    comment.setPostingDate(new Date());
    comment.setPageId(Long.valueOf(pageId));
    try {

        return comment;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (SignInNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Just for additonal information i am using  jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.1

Comment: Have you checked hit url is same for both?

Comment: Share the request URL for req1 and req2?

Comment: may be `"json"` at end.

Comment: You've cut off the code before the end (I'd expect at least a `);` to end it). Might also be useful to see what's actually done with the response inside the function passed to `.done()`.

Comment: Kindly add controller code and full ajax call code.

Comment: The controller is working fine

Comment: @Anthony: No it's okay. I have in my original javascript no typo mistake. I forgot to put it here. :)

Comment: try entering the url directly insted of c:url like this  $.get("/createcomment", and see what you get

Comment: the URL is okay...the controller is working fine. The controller is also returning fine. What i see the problem is something with the browser because when i refresh the browser the first request again goes correctly and than it messes up from the second request. I debugged each step in the controller and the controller works perfect so i don't think its the  URL problem  but something else is wrong somewhere else.

Comment: @SaurabhKumar, Cannot be said to be URL is ok as its double quotes  are not properly closed. All other parts seems to be ok. When I saw the strange behavior (your issue of different responses) I created a test (with out jstl c:url tag)  and the ajax request and controller methods are all working fine. I copied the same method and created a Comment class. One more issue I saw in your url is beginning forward slash (/). try removing that also

Comment: which double quotes qre you talking about . I checked remove the slash also but no luck

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might want to check if your method throws a `NumberFormatException` or `SignInNotFoundException`, in which case it returns null. Your network log shows that 0 bytes of data have been transferred.